# How do I get a progress dialog to show up when any link is clicked in a Webview

Tags: android, webview, progressdialog

I have a header with some buttons in it and a webview below it. I have a working progress dialog for when the page originally opens and when a button is clicked. The problem is when I click any links inside of the webview a progress dialog doesn't show. Does anyone know the best method to make this happen? I included below the code for my WebViewClient and one of the buttons.

```
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
             @Override
             public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                 view.loadUrl(url);
                 return true;
             }
             ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(myActivity.this, "","Loading...", true);
             public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                 dialog.dismiss();
             }
        });
        final Button btnCategory = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCategory);
        btnCategory.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             public void onClick(View v) {
                mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
                     ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(myActivity.this, "","Loading...", true);
                     public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                         dialog.dismiss();
                     }
                });
                mWebView.loadUrl("http://mywebsite.com/page");
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to show a dialog you could just toggle the visibility of a progress bar.
I haven't tried it myself but it could look like this:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frameLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:visibility="invisible" >
    </ProgressBar>
```

Comment: It makes sense but I guess what I am having issues with is how to get my app to recognize that a link has been clicked in the Webview and toggle the progress bar. Is there a way for an app to recognize that the url of the webview has changed?

Answer (score 0):

you could use a relativelayout to include the webview and the progressbar (which is centered in the relativelayout).